# How to get the queries made to AWS/RDS in Grafana

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a grafana instance running in a kubernetes cluster. I have set up a CoudWatch Datasource with the corresponding credentials and I can retrieve some metrics.

My specific need is to know if I can retrieve the queries to the DB (or SQL digest) like RDS does in TOP SQL on AWS Console (https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6sO4.png) or something similar, so I can check the query performance.

Thank  you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following steps:

- First, Enable the Query logging for Amazon RDS: eg. [PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-query-logging/) and [MySQL](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-logs/)
- Then, [publish the logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Procedural.UploadtoCloudWatch.html)
- And, in the Grafana side, [add the AWS CloudWatch data source integration](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/#:%7E:text=Configure%20the%20CloudWatch%20data%20source,details%2C%20see%20AWS%20authentication%20topic.)

This way you be able to get your queries in Grafana like this [Cloudwatch Logs integration example](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/758).

If you want you can [analise/filter your RDS logs using CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html) in Grafana.

Comment: Thank you @valdeci for your answer. This instructions I see they work for PostgreSQL but I have MySQL instead. Just in the first link you share I see the difference that neither of the parameters (log_statemet and log_min_duration_statement) exists for me. Do you know a way to manage this situation?

Comment: I updated my question to add the docs of enabling logs with MYSQL